# IDE: Browse remote host and drag&drop local files and folders

Tags: php, web, ftp, ide

in our agency we have about 30 websites. It is nonsense to have all websites locally on MAC, so I need IDE with benefits of better FTP client.

The IDE should have these features:

- manage my FTP accounts
- browse remote host
- drag and drop local files and folders to remote host
- edit remote files

Is there any plugin for any IDE with these features?
I actually do not care about IDE: PHPStorm, Atom, VS Code, Sublime, ...

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you are not using version control then... I would recommend that and having local copies of all projects.

Comment: We are talking about 30 wordpress websites, this is nonsense to run all sites locally with databases. This is why I need edit files on remote host.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) for your need, I've been using for the last 5-6 years for qa/production deployment. Its available for download across all type of platforms, please visit [here](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php)

Comment: Thanks, but FileZilla is not an IDE, so I cant edit directly files on remote host. Or can I?

Comment: It doesn't have a text editor by default, but you can set a default application for editing. You can close the file after editing, It works as simple, 

And if you're looking for more features, please have a look at Cloud9 IDE, 
now Amazon acquired it.. please see here https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/